# I am working on a webpage with jQuery in and it makes my laptop crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, hardware

I have a Dell Vostro laptop with Windows 7, 4GB RAM and intel i3 and I check my website under FireFox, Chrome and SeaMonkey.

The page is here and jQuery is included on the html

http://magician.sdf-eu.org/zee/Click%20This%20One%20To%20View%20What%20I%20Have%20So%20Far.html

If I do not open the webpage I am working on, my laptop does not crash

Thanks a lot for your help, Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include jquery.js twice. In my experience this can cause jquery to consume a lot of cpu.

Your laptop may be overheating.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will definitely try that